# Why does cast always returns zero only when debugging in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Only on my machine this happens.
Basically if i run the following all is as expected:

```
        double d = 500.22;
        int i = (int)d;
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
```

Output is 500.

However if i put a breakpoint on the first line and step through, i always reverts to zero and the output is 0.

I've tested this on other machines and I cannot replicate, I've even reinstalled VS2010 and it still happens.  So I'm thinking it must be some sort of environment setting that I have on my system, but I cannot figure out what.

Anyone else had this issue and how do I get rid of it.

Cheers.

EDIT:  It appears that the issue is just with the 2nd line.  If I put a break point on the 1st line and then just F5 over it, then it's all ok.  But if I step into/over the 2nd line, the casting doesn't appear to work and i stays at 0.
I also tried setting i to 1 first and then seeing if the cast works, but it changes i back to 0 and removes my initial value of 1.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you step through, or did you step over?

Comment: If you mean step into or over, then i've done both.

Comment: Could you provide screenshots? Are you saying that the debugger states that i == 0 in the tooltip when hovering? Or does it state i == 0 in the watch window? Or immediate window? Where's your code when that happens? Breaking at Console.WriteLine?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you seeing that i is 0 in the watch window, or is it because the Console.WriteLine is outputting 0?  It's kindof a stupid question, because Console.WriteLine SHOULD write whatever i is, but then i should be 500 in the first place... so we need to pin down exactly which piece is behaving terribly wrong.

Comment: Screenshot provided.  If i add a watcher, it still shows 0.  If i run the same command (int)d; in the immediate window it casts it as normal (500).

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint on the second line and step over?  And the third?  Again, these should all be the same, but...

Comment: That is really bizarre.  What happens if you use Convert.ToInt32?

Comment: Also, what if you declare int i at the beginning of Main, instead of declaring and setting at the same time?

Comment: @JamesB - It's odd cos if I use Convert.ToInt32 it's ok.  So it must be something to do with using (int) in VS.  And re all your other suggestions, still the same issue.  Except, putting a break only on line 3, that is ok and i is then 500.  I guess that's because i didn't step over the cast.

Comment: I modified my answer to say use Convert.ToInt32 : )  I don't like not knowing, but because (int) truncates instead of rounding, it's the better solution, anyway.  +1 on the question for finding a truly bizarre and incorrect behavior!

Comment: What other values of d fail?  501.22?  500.99?  500?  1500.22?  Just curious how specific this issue is.  I tried to reproduce it and can't.

Comment: Also, what if you declare i as a short and cast that way?  Is this issue specific to (int)?

Comment: yeah casting to a short has the same issue.  Doing it directly with i = (int)500.55 seems to be fine, however.

Comment: I would open an issue with Microsoft at this point... you can file a bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio?wa=wsignin1.0 - I wish I could reproduce this, I'd love to play with it.

Comment: Are you by any chance compiling with optimizations turned on? If the local variable i is not actually used then the optimizer might remove it from the program entirely; that can deeply confuse the debugger. It might be that i has the value zero because *there is no storage for i*. (Though typically in that case the debugger says "there is no such thing as i" rather than reporting that its value is zero.)

Comment: @Eric - sorry I've confused matters by pasting in a screenshot with a different console.writeline to my original post.  I was playing around with it to see what happens.  So even when i do use the local variable i in the console.writeline, it still behaves the same.  And Optimization is off anyhow.

Comment: Yeah, originally you had Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());... and it still didn't work.  And the truly bizarre point is that if you let it run through without breaking, it works correctly, but if you stop on that line and F10 over it, it fails.  To me that's a smoking gun that it's not a compiler/optimization issue, but a bug with the debugger itself.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the framework itself?  Enable .NET Framework source stepping, and see what .NET is trying to do when you F11 into the cast.  ** Never mind, apparently the code that does the casting is not included in the distributed .NET source code, at least I can't get the debugger to step into anything on the cast.  Oh, well.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have all the latest .NET Framework service patches?  There are some even for the 4.0 framework, though I haven't heard of anything like this yet.

*** Edit ***
Regarding my other suggestions, casting to an int truncates, and Convert.ToInt32 rounds, so Convert.ToInt32 is what you generally want anyway (especially if it's working).

Comment: I think i'm fully up to date as running the windows update didn't pick anything up.

Comment: that's a good point, i didn't realise that casting truncates and doesn't round.  I always wondered what the diff was. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run VS with `/SafeMode` or `/ResetSettings` command line args

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however still the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your screen shot you aren't outputting *i*, you're outputting *d*--you aren't actually using *i*. I can't repro the behavior you've described, but I get close if I put a breakpoint on the WriteLine in Release mode: *i* doesn't even exist in that case. But why should it, you're not using it. (Note I used the code in your screen shot for repro, not the code that actually uses *i*.)

Comment: whoops, sorry yeah i made a modification to see what it would do, but still the same issue.  Anyway, that is irrelvant as the problem is with the 2nd line not with the console line.  I'll try and repo your Release mode issue and see.